# Deployment of pickle model in a python flask app on Azure App Service

Tags: python, pickle, azure-web-app-service, internal-server-error

I am trying to deploy a pickel model (loaded within a flask app) on Azure. I connected my github repository so that deployment automatically starts when the github repository gets updated. Within this github repository is also my pickel model.
The deployed flask app works fine up to the point where I call the unpickeled model. Notably, unpickeling the model does not throw an error, only when I use the model `model.transform(data)` I get a 500 server error.

This is how I load the model:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
   model = pickle.load(open( "model.pkl", "rb" ))
   app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

On my local machine everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally solved this after learning how to access the diagnostic logs. It turns out that the model-loading needs to be set as a global variable:

```
model = pickle.load(open( "model.pkl", "rb" ))

if __name__ == "__main__": 
   app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Strangely that was not necessary on my local machine.